# How to attach google map with email in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am using Iframe for google map attach with email but get message "The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe".
Please Help Out.
With Regards,
Bvenkat Jeewesh

Comment: I would say (very uncertain) that you have to create a custom block that you can include a good representation of google maps inside an email. Curious to see other comments/answers

Comment: It seems this is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24355007/is-there-no-way-to-embed-a-google-map-into-an-html-email

Comment: Is it a static map that will be the same for all subscribers? Or is it dynamic, different for all subscribers?